# Delete li entry in database with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I am working on a website where the user can enter the money he owes a friend. On one page the user can see all the entrys he made so far and should be able to delete them aswell. All entrys are inserted in a DB. For this overview page I use following structure:

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <?php 
    $isEmpty = true;
    while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
        if ($data['isDebt'] == 0) {
            $isEmpty = false; ?>
            <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" autocomplete="off">
                <li class="list-group-item" name="Debt_ID" value="<?php echo $data['Debt_ID'] ?>"><span class="badge"><?php echo $data['value']; ?></span><?php echo $data['name']; ?>
                    <button name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger pull-right">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;
                    </button>
                </li>
            </form>
  <?php }
    } 
    if ($isEmpty) { ?>
        <li class="list-group-item">No debt!</li>    
    <?php 
    } ?>
</ul>
```

One debt entry has the following values:

- Debt_ID (numeric)
- Name    (like "pizza from jack")
- Value   (the price. for example "10")

The button for each li element should delete the entry in the DB via Debt_ID. I've used the following SQL statement so far:

```
DELETE FROM Debt WHERE Debt_ID='$debt_ID';
```

In PHP it looked like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['delete'])) {
    $debt_ID = trim($_POST['Debt_ID']);
    $res = mysql_query("DELETE FROM Debt WHERE Debt_ID='$debt_ID';");

    if ($res) {
        $errTyp = "success";
        $errMSG = "Successfully deleted";
    } else {
        $errTyp = "danger";
        $errMSG = "Error occured";
    }
 }
```

My problem right now is that I am not able to get the Debt_ID which I've entered with PHP in the `li` element. Does anyone know a better approach or what I am doing wrong? 
I am developping with Cloud9 so I could invite someone if interested.

Comment: Create `input type=hidden` with debt id

Comment: `<li>` is not an input. If you're going to want to use something like that, use a hidden input.

Comment: there's also no jquery/ajax in here, so if those aren't at fault or contributing to the syntax error you made, then those tags should be removed.

Comment: @u_mulder our comments are like, 2 seconds apart. GMTA I guess *lol* I didn't see yours when I was typing mine. But yeah, that is the solution here.

Comment: How do I retrieve the ID from the input field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load all the debts, you can do that with a `select` statement and loop through the result set. In the loop you can put the id in hidden inputs in each li element:

```
$sql = "SELECT debt_id, name, value FROM debts WHERE user_id = " . $user_id;
$result = $conn -> query($sql);

if ($result -> num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<li>
                  <span>' . $row["name"] . '</span>
                  <span>' . $row["value"] . '</span>
                  <input type="hidden" value="' . $row['debt_id'] . ' name="id-to-delete">
              </li>';
    }
} else {
    echo "no results";
}
```

The delete.php file should contain:

```
<?php  
    if (isset($_POST['id-to-delete'])) {
        $idToDelete = $_POST['id-to-delete'];

        // sql to delete a record
        $sql = 'DELETE FROM debts WHERE debt_id=' . $idToDelete;

        if ($conn->query($sql)) {
            echo "Record deleted successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error deleting record: " . $conn->error;
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

After the form element simply add

```
<input type="hidden" name="Debt_ID" value="<?php echo $data['Debt_ID'] ?>">
```

Then remove the same information from the li element.

When submitting a form, input elements with a name attribute are what gets passed along to the next page.